# Using same function 2nd time

Tags: php, image

I'm declaring the following function to get a random image from a directory. I want to use the same function in same code to get random image from a different directory. Now the problem is that I have to change $path but I have already used it in declaration while i want to use the different path when I use the function 2nd time

Declaration part

```
function getImagesFromDir($path) { 
$images = array(); 
if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) { 
    while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) { 
        // checks for gif, jpg, png 
        if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) { 
            $images[] = $img_file; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($img_dir); 
} 
return $images; 
}
```

I use it this way 1st time

```
$root = ''; 

$path = 'frames/';

$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path); 

$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
```

How shud i use it 2nd time so that it chooses image from different directory.

Comment: How are you calling the function? The error suggests that you're actually trying to redeclare it rather than just call it

Comment: you want to use or redeclare? You aren't calling the function anywhere in the code above.

Comment: You can *use* (call) a function as many times as you like, but you can only *declare* it once. `function some_func() { $do = 'something'; } some_func(); some_func();`

Comment: Check if ";" is missing after your method, so it is displaying redeclaration error. To use this method you need to call it likewise -- getImagesFromDir($path);

Comment: @swapnesh `Check if ";" is missing after your method, so it is displaying redeclaration error.` - errr... sorry, what?

Comment: @DaveRandom  i just mean to say if he is calling in this way func() but missed that ; [func();<-correct] so might he is getting that error as while parsing it is taking redeclaration of the method..this is what i thought before the new edit.. i hope it makes sense and let me know if something i too was missing :)

Comment: Pls wrt th whl wrds, t's sr to rd.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't *call* the function twice, but *declare* it twice.

declaration:

```
function getImagesFromDir($path) { 
$images = array(); 
if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) { 
    while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) { 
        // checks for gif, jpg, png 
        if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) { 
            $images[] = $img_file; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($img_dir); 
} 
return $images; 
}
```

calls:

```
$images1 = getImagesFromDir("/var/www/images1");
$images2 = getImagesFromDir("/var/www/images2");
```

if you write

```
function getImagesFromDir($path) ....
```

again anywhere it gets *redeclared* and PHP don't supports this

this also happens if you require the file, which declares the function, more than once.

-- edit ---

```
$strRoot = '';

$astrImages = array();

$astrImages[] = array( 'path' => 'frames/', 'image' => '' );
$astrImages[] = array( 'path' => 'etc1/', 'image' => '' );
$astrImages[] = array( 'path' => 'etc2/', 'image' => '' );
$astrImages[] = array( 'path' => 'etc3/', 'image' => '' );


foreach( $astrImages as $nIndex => $astrImage )
{
  $imgList = getImagesFromDir($strRoot . $astrImage['path']); 

  $astrImages[$nIndex]['image'] = getRandomFromArray($imgList); 
}
```

Comment: i did the same thing. But the problem is tht i hv to use $path once again so it takes the 2nd value of $ path when i need the 1st value. $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg("user.jpg");
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("$path$img");
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

Comment: I'm merging a random image to another image. and i hv to do this twice.

Comment: edited. with the current solution you would have every image and corresponding path in one array.